# SQL Server 2008 log size management problems

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logfiles

I'm trying to **shrink the log** of a database AND **set the recovery to simple**, but always there is an error, whatever i try.

```
USE 4_o5;
GO
ALTER DATABASE 4_o5
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (4_o5_log, 10);
GO
```

the output of **sp_helpfile** says that log file is located under (hosted solution):

```
I:\dataroot\4_o5_log.LDF
```

please help me perform this operation as the log file got large when importing a lot of data and now this info is no longer needed, have multiple (lots of) backups since then.

the exact **error message** when performing the query above is:

```
incorrect syntax near '4'.
RECOVERY is not a recognized SET option.
incorrect syntax near _5_log'.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (also have SQL Server Express installed locally, SQL Server 2008 proper installed at provider (shared))

thnx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
USE [4_o5] --need brackets with this DB name, as marc_s commented
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 10)
```

[DBCC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) also takes the internal file id number and I see you're having problems separating logical and physical file names... which leads me to assume you don't have multiple log files or NDFs etc and the log file will *always* be 2

However, **why** do you want to shrink anyway?

To change recovery model: `ALTER DATABASE [4_o5] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE`

Comment: yeah, shrink worked with: **USE [4_o5]; DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 10)** so thank you. can you also maybe please advise on how to set the logging to simple. an the reason has to do with how the provider allocates the space for the database, because it can reach the limit of expansion available - it was very near it. talking with them to upgrade us soon. just had to deal with this first.

Comment: the USE won't work if the database name starts with a numerical value - you need to use  `USE [4_o5]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
USE [4_o5];
GO
ALTER DATABASE [4_o5] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE ([4_o5_log], 10);
GO
```

Your database name starting with a numeric value is a bit unusual - try putting it in square brackets.

**UPDATE:** for the `DBCC SHRINKFILE`, you need the *logical* name of the log file - that's the `name` property from the `sp_helpfile` call. And you also need to put it in square brackets:

```
USE [4_o5]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE ([4_o5_log], 10)
GO
```

Comment: yeah, provider requirement for the numeric start.

Comment: now i get a slightly changed error: **incorrect syntax near '4'. incorrect syntax near 'GO'. incorrect syntax near 'GO'.**

Comment: @b0x0rz: sorry, you also need square brackets around the database name in the USE statement.

Comment: yeah i put them there also - then the error is: **incorrect syntax near 'GO'. incorrect syntax near 'GO'. incorrect syntax near 'GO'.**

Comment: You shouldn't need the `GO` lines

Comment: The semicolon and GO should be doing the same thing

Comment: now the error is: **could not locate '4_o5_log' for database '4_o5' in sys.database_files. the file either does not exist, or was dropped.**